# Anyone knows a tool to generate a dot (graphviz) file from a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, generator, graphviz, dot

Given a Makefile (command are not needed in this example):

```
program: src0.o src1.o

src0.o: src0.c src0.h

src1.o: src1.c src1.h src0.h
```

Does anyone knows of a tool that can generate a dot file?

As follows:

```
digraph "Dependencies" {
"src0.h" -> "src0.o";
"src0.h" -> "src1.o";
"src1.h" -> "src1.o";
"src0.c" -> "src0.o";
"src1.c" -> "src1.o";
"src0.o" -> "program";
"src1.o" -> "program";
}
```

Note that this tool could also be smart enough to shortcut the .o files, and pretend that the c files depend on the headers they include.

```
digraph "Dependencies" {
"src0.h" -> "src0.c";
"src0.h" -> "src1.c";
"src1.h" -> "src1.c";
"src0.c" -> "program";
"src1.c" -> "program";
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create Makefile graphs using GraphViz? Does this do what you need?

https://metacpan.org/pod/Makefile::GraphViz or https://metacpan.org/pod/GraphViz::Makefile